# How can we create two instances of memcached server in same server in different port?

Tags: memcached

I tried to add in the way
-l 11211
-l 11212 
in memcached conf file. But it is just listening to first one i.e 1121

Comment: For the simulation of clustering environment I am running two tomcats in one server, but both the tomcat servers are sharing one mysql server. Please correct me if I am wrong.
For the sticky session sharing purpose I need to run memcahed as daemon.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's what memcached says the `-l` command is for:

```
-l <addr>     interface to listen on (default: INADDR_ANY, all addresses)
              <addr> may be specified as host:port. If you don't specify
              a port number, the value you specified with -p or -U is
              used. You may specify multiple addresses separated by comma
              or by using -l multiple times
```

First off you need to specify the interface you want memcached to listen on if you are using the `-l` flag. Use `0.0.0.0` for all interfaces and use `127.0.0.1` is you just want to be able to access memcached from `localhost`. Second, don't use two `-l` flags. Use only one and separate each address by a comma. The command below should do what you want.

```
memcached -l 0.0.0.0:11211,0.0.0.0:11212
```

Keep in mind that this will have one memcached instance listen on two ports. To have two memcached instances on one machine run these two commands.

```
memcached -p 11211 -d

memcached -p 11212 -d
```

Comment: Wow thanks this is really going to help me out with my cluster.

Comment: none of these work for me on 1.4.2 and the referenced documentation no longer seems to exist.

Comment: None is this is working for me also.Posting below the error I am getting.

Comment: D:\sw\memcache\memcached-1.2.5-win32-bin>memcached -l 0.0.0.0:12213,0.0.0.0:12212
getaddrinfo(): No error
failed to listen

Answer (score 73):

First I used mikewied's solution, but then I bumped into the problem of auto starting the daemon. Another confusing thing in that solution is that it doesn't use the config from etc. I was about to create my own start up scripts in /etc/init.d but then I looked into /etc/init.d/memcached file and saw this beautiful solution

```
# Usage:
# cp /etc/memcached.conf /etc/memcached_server1.conf
# cp /etc/memcached.conf /etc/memcached_server2.conf
# start all instances:
# /etc/init.d/memcached start
# start one instance:
# /etc/init.d/memcached start server1
# stop all instances:
# /etc/init.d/memcached stop
# stop one instance:
# /etc/init.d/memcached stop server1
# There is no "status" command.
```

Basically readers of this question just need to read the `/etc/init.d/memcached` file.

Cheers

Comment: This should be the chosen solution

Comment: I think your init script must be different. On CenOS 6 I read the file /etc/init.d/memcached and I don't see how the commands you listed would work without modifying it. Maybe I am slow :)

Comment: Please be aware, this does not work for Debain Jessie because of this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784357. There are workarounds in the ticket.

Comment: Worked well after doing this little change: `cp /lib/systemd/system/memcached.service /lib/systemd/system/memcached@.service`
and editing that new file like on this link: [Editing service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770784/how-do-i-setup-multiple-memcached-instances-running-on-different-ports/891367#891367)

Answer (score 3):

The answer from David Dzhagayev is the best one. If you don't have the correct version of memcache init script, here is the one he is talking about:

It should work with any linux distro using init.

```
#! /bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:            memcached
# Required-Start:      $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:       $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:                $local_fs
# Should-Stop:         $local_fs
# Default-Start:       2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:                0 1 6
# Short-Description:   Start memcached daemon
# Description:         Start up memcached, a high-performance memory caching daemon
### END INIT INFO

# Usage:
# cp /etc/memcached.conf /etc/memcached_server1.conf
# cp /etc/memcached.conf /etc/memcached_server2.conf
# start all instances:
# /etc/init.d/memcached start
# start one instance:
# /etc/init.d/memcached start server1
# stop all instances:
# /etc/init.d/memcached stop
# stop one instance:
# /etc/init.d/memcached stop server1
# There is no "status" command.

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/memcached
DAEMONNAME=memcached
DAEMONBOOTSTRAP=/usr/share/memcached/scripts/start-memcached
DESC=memcached

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
test -x $DAEMONBOOTSTRAP || exit 0

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Edit /etc/default/memcached to change this.
ENABLE_MEMCACHED=no
test -r /etc/default/memcached && . /etc/default/memcached


FILES=(/etc/memcached_*.conf)
# check for alternative config schema
if [ -r "${FILES[0]}" ]; then
  CONFIGS=()
  for FILE in "${FILES[@]}";
  do
    # remove prefix
    NAME=${FILE#/etc/}
    # remove suffix
    NAME=${NAME%.conf}

    # check optional second param
    if [ $# -ne 2 ];
    then
      # add to config array
      CONFIGS+=($NAME)
    elif [ "memcached_$2" == "$NAME" ];
    then
      # use only one memcached
      CONFIGS=($NAME)
      break;
    fi;
  done;

  if [ ${#CONFIGS[@]} == 0 ];
  then
    echo "Config not exist for: $2" >&2
    exit 1
  fi;
else
  CONFIGS=(memcached)
fi;

CONFIG_NUM=${#CONFIGS[@]}
for ((i=0; i < $CONFIG_NUM; i++)); do
  NAME=${CONFIGS[${i}]}
  PIDFILE="/var/run/${NAME}.pid"

case "$1" in
  start)
       echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
       if [ $ENABLE_MEMCACHED = yes ]; then
            start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec "$DAEMONBOOTSTRAP" -- /etc/${NAME}.conf $PIDFILE
            echo "$NAME."
       else
            echo "$NAME disabled in /etc/default/memcached."
       fi
       ;;
  stop)
       echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
       start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry 5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
       echo "$NAME."
       rm -f $PIDFILE
       ;;

  restart|force-reload)
       #
       #       If the "reload" option is implemented, move the "force-reload"
       #       option to the "reload" entry above. If not, "force-reload" is
       #       just the same as "restart".
       #
       echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
       start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry 5 --pidfile $PIDFILE
       rm -f $PIDFILE
       if [ $ENABLE_MEMCACHED = yes ]; then
                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec "$DAEMONBOOTSTRAP" -- /etc/${NAME}.conf $PIDFILE
                echo "$NAME."
       else
            echo "$NAME disabled in /etc/default/memcached."
       fi
       ;;
  status)
       status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON $NAME  && exit 0 || exit $?
       ;;
  *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
done;

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else stumbles upon this question, there is a bug on the debian distribution of memcached (which means flavours like Ubuntu would also be affected).

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784357

Because of this bug, even when you have separate configuration files, when you run `sudo service memcached restart`, only the default configuration file in `/etc/memcached.conf` will be loaded.

As mentioned in the [comment here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784357#13), the temporary solution is to

1. Remove `/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service`
2. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` (don't worry, it is safe to do
   so)
3. Finally, run `sudo service memcached restart` if you are okay with losing all cache information. If not, run `sudo service memcached force-reload`

Comment: Thank you! Only reload doesn't exist, I got `Usage: /etc/init.d/memcached_server1 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}`, I used `restart` instead

Comment: Ah! Edited my original comment for clarity :)

Comment: Thanks @narasi, combined yours and Davyd Dzhahaiev answered and it finally worked on Ubuntu. It also auto opens with reboot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, very good answer, Tristan CHARBONNIER.
Please replace code into file /usr/share/memcached/scripts/start-memcached:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# start-memcached
# 2003/2004 - Jay Bonci 
# This script handles the parsing of the /etc/memcached.conf file
# and was originally created for the Debian distribution.
# Anyone may use this little script under the same terms as
# memcached itself.

use strict;

if($> != 0 and $< != 0)
{
    print STDERR "Only root wants to run start-memcached.\n";
    exit;
}

my $params; my $etchandle; my $etcfile = "/etc/memcached.conf";

# This script assumes that memcached is located at /usr/bin/memcached, and
# that the pidfile is writable at /var/run/memcached.pid

my $memcached = "/usr/bin/memcached";
my $pidfile = "/var/run/memcached.pid";

if (scalar(@ARGV) == 2) {
    $etcfile = shift(@ARGV);
    $pidfile = shift(@ARGV);
}

# If we don't get a valid logfile parameter in the /etc/memcached.conf file,
# we'll just throw away all of our in-daemon output. We need to re-tie it so
# that non-bash shells will not hang on logout. Thanks to Michael Renner for 
# the tip
my $fd_reopened = "/dev/null";

    sub handle_logfile
    {
        my ($logfile) = @_;
        $fd_reopened = $logfile;
    }

    sub reopen_logfile
    {
        my ($logfile) = @_;

        open *STDERR, ">>$logfile";
        open *STDOUT, ">>$logfile";
        open *STDIN, ">>/dev/null";
        $fd_reopened = $logfile;
    }

# This is set up in place here to support other non -[a-z] directives

my $conf_directives = {
    "logfile" => \&handle_logfile,
};

if(open $etchandle, $etcfile)
{
    foreach my $line (< $etchandle>)
    {
        $line ||= "";
        $line =~ s/\#.*//g;
        $line =~ s/\s+$//g;
        $line =~ s/^\s+//g;
        next unless $line;
        next if $line =~ /^\-[dh]/;

        if($line =~ /^[^\-]/)
        {
            my ($directive, $arg) = $line =~ /^(.*?)\s+(.*)/; 
            $conf_directives->{$directive}->($arg);
            next;
        }

        push @$params, $line;       
    }

}else{
    $params = [];
}

    push @$params, "-u root" unless(grep "-u", @$params);
    $params = join " ", @$params;

if(-e $pidfile)
{
    open PIDHANDLE, "$pidfile";
    my $localpid = <PIDHANDLE>;
    close PIDHANDLE;

    chomp $localpid;
    if(-d "/proc/$localpid")
    {
        print STDERR "memcached is already running.\n"; 
        exit;       
    }else{
        `rm -f $localpid`;
    }

}

my $pid = fork();

if($pid == 0)
{
        reopen_logfile($fd_reopened);
        exec "$memcached $params";
        exit(0);

}else{
    if(open PIDHANDLE,">$pidfile")
    {
        print PIDHANDLE $pid;
        close PIDHANDLE;
    }else{

        print STDERR "Can't write pidfile to $pidfile.\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution to Centos 6**

First copy `/etc/sysconfig/memcached` to `/etc/sysconfig/memcached2` and write new settings to the new file.

Then copy `/etc/init.d/memcached` to `/etc/init.d/memcached2` and change in the new file:

- PORT to your new port (it should be reset from `/etc/sysconfig/memcached2`, so we do it just in case)
- `/etc/sysconfig/memcached` to `/etc/sysconfig/memcached2`
- `/var/run/memcached/memcached.pid` to `/var/run/memcached/memcached2.pid`
- `/var/lock/subsys/memcached` to `/var/lock/subsys/memcached2`

Now you can use `service memcached2 start`, `service memcached2 stop` etc. Don't forget `chkconfig memcached2 on` to run it when machine boots up.

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/memcached.conf you can just edit like below

-l 192.168.112.22,127.0.0.1

must use **comma** between two ip address