# how to change the port number of the memcached server other than 11211

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I wanted to have two instance of the memcachedClient on the same set of the servers , so I can store one set of keys on the fisrt client1 and the other on the second client.So nI am declaring the two instance like

```
MemcachedClient client1 =new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
                AddrUtil.getAddresses("172.22.65.111:11211 172.22.65.11:11211")); and 
MemcachedClient client2 =new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
                AddrUtil.getAddresses("172.22.65.111:11212 172.22.65.11:11212"));
```

here i am specifying that client2 is listening on the other port 11212.
but i am getting java.net.ConnectException:

```
Connection refused: no further information.
```

Due to the client2 declaration.

I have installed memcached and then executed the commands `memcached -p 11211 -d start` and `memcached -p 11212 -d start` in the CMD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we create two instances of memcached server in same server in different port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928387/how-can-we-create-two-instances-of-memcached-server-in-same-server-in-different)

Comment: I uninstall the  memcached server and then install the server on the port 11212 Like memcached -d install -m 1024 -p 11212. and then excuted a program which contain MemcachedClient client1 =new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
    AddrUtil.getAddresses("172.22.65.111:11212"));. but i got the same error java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information .

Comment: you need to see if the server really started..

Comment: yes server is already started. just now i hv install the server like mmemcached -d install.Then executed memcached -m 1024 -p 11212 -d start and memcached -m 1024 -p 11211 -d start. its working the i specify the port no. 11211. But not on the port no 11212. why can u help pls.

Comment: Make sure that your firewall is not blocking port 11212.

Comment: To check if the memcached is up and runing and client has an access to the port use telnet to connect to 172.22.65.111:11212.

Comment: I have stoped my firewall and then chcked .But its giving me the same error

Comment: i have install memcached like memcached -d install -m 512 172.22.65.111 -p 11212. In this case also its not listening to the port 11212. its listening on port 11211. to check it i used 'telnet localhost 11212' it gets failed when trying to connect. Do u people have any suggestion where i am going wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `memcached.conf` file worked for me when I was having similar problems. It seems that memcached is ignoring the options you give it and just using the options which are in the file.