# Multiple instance of memcache on same server

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I am using a linux server. I have done a single memcache installation and all is fine. We are adding another application on the same server. It also requires memcache.

How do I set up memcache so that each application gets its own instance of memcache?

I am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: It's very simple... start Memcached on another port, and configure your application to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we create two instances of memcached server in same server in different port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928387/how-can-we-create-two-instances-of-memcached-server-in-same-server-in-different)

Answer (score 1):

By default, memcache run on port 11211. But you can run as many memcache's instances on one server as you wish. Just specify another port to run - and configure your application to connect to the another port.
Ex:

- instance with 64M on port 11212

  memcache -p 11212 -m 64 -u nobody -d
- instance with 128M on port 11213

  memcache -p 11213 -m 128 -u nobody -d
- instance with 20G on port 11214

  memcache -p 11214 -m 20480 -u nobody -d